# Need to change color of text based on XML variable value

Tags: xml, xslt, conditional-statements

I would like to conditionally change the color of displayed text in XML file basd on value returned in variable.
It will be either 'Yes' or 'No'.

This is the XML:

```html
<tr style="height: 18px;">
  <td style="width: 163px; height: 18px;"><strong>Validation Required?</strong></td>
  <td style="width: 50px; height: 18px;"><xsl:value-of select="Validation_Required"></xsl:value-of></td>
  <td style="width: 652px; height: 18px;" colspan="4"></td>
</tr>
```

I want the text of the `Validation_Required?` value to display red when the value of it is 'Yes' and black when it is 'No'.

I was having no luck with this approach so far:

```html
<xsl:when test="Validation_Required='Yes'">
```

I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Variables in XSLT are accessed with a `$` prefix, so to access your variable `Validation_Required` you have to prefix it.

Changing your code to

```
<tr style="height: 18px;">
  <td style="width: 163px; height: 18px;"><strong>Validation Required?</strong></td>
  <td style="width: 50px; height: 18px;">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$Validation_Required='Yes'">
        <span style="color:rgb(255, 0, 0);">
          <xsl:value-of select="$Validation_Required"></xsl:value-of>
        </span>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="$Validation_Required='No'">
        <span style="color:rgb(0, 0, 0);">
          <xsl:value-of select="$Validation_Required"></xsl:value-of>
        </span>
      </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
  </td>
  <td style="width: 652px; height: 18px;" colspan="4"></td>
</tr>
```

changes the color of one `td` element bases on the value of a `Validation_Required` variable.

Comment: I got an error with your ode concerning the variable. I removed the $ signs and it works perfectly. Tell me more about $ please. It seems I don't have a need for them to get this to work. ??

Comment: If you don't need the `$` prefix, you're probably accessing an element of your XML and not a variable of your XSLT. But I'm glad that my answer helped you (in a way). [Here at W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ref_xsl_el_variable.asp) is an example of an XSLT variable. [Here is another link at XML.com](https://www.xml.com/pub/a/2001/02/07/trxml9.html) explaing the use of variables.

Comment: Terrific. Thank you! Yes I was accessing an XML variable and not part of the XSL.

Comment: Just being picky: you were accessing _an XML element_ (and not a variable).